# Globalize & globalize-accessors single form translations - throwing error when updating attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, friendly-id, globalize3, globalize

I wanted to make a form for creating and updating a model, with support for adding/editing translations for multiple languages inline.

This is how my form looks like:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @category], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% Category.globalize_attribute_names.each do |lang| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label lang %><br>
      <%= f.text_field lang %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Strangely, everything works fine when I`m creating a model. But when I try to edit it I get this error:

undefined method `name_en' for #Category::Translation:0x007f3ce896afd8>

I said strangely, because it works fine in the console. When i type:

```
Category.friendly.find("men-shoes").name_en
```

everything works fine. (I`m using friendlyID gem).

I have no idea what the problem could be. I even don`t know why is it fetching Category::Translation, should`n it be just Category?

Thanks